# Customising the multi bar chart?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a multi bar chart that needs to be customized in a way that each bar of a key data needs to be split into two bars. 
After the render I removed the rects and addded new multiple rect's each. Now, the issue is how can I bind those data? It seems tooltip doesnot work because data has been removed.
http://plnkr.co/edit/C0ZXulGAa21PbjURbcug?p=preview

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-group')[0].forEach(function (d, i) {
            var group = d3.select(d);
            group.selectAll('rect')[0].forEach(function(data){
                var rect = d3.select(data);
                var x = rect.attr('x');
                var y = rect.attr('y');
                var tr = rect.attr('transform');
                var h = rect.attr('height');
                var w = rect.attr('width');
                var fill = rect.style('fill');
                var stroke = rect.style('stroke');
                var d = rect.data();
                rect.remove();
                group.data(d).append('rect').attr('class', 'nv-bar positive')
                    .attr("x", x).attr('y', y).attr('transform', tr).attr('height', h).attr('width', w)
                    .style('fill', fill).style('stroke', stroke);
                group.data(d).append('rect').attr('class', 'nv-bar positive')
                    .attr("x", x).attr('y', y).attr('transform', tr).attr('height', h/2).attr('width', w)
                    .style('fill', 'white').style('stroke', stroke);

            });




        });
```